# how to use promises in nested function calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Just as I thought I understood promises... I have commented my code below where I am struggling, but in essence, I just can't understand why when the code below is run I get the following result

```
console.log("Finished Processing sheets")
console.log("Processing Errors")
console.log("sheet has completed processing")
```

When I would have expected

```
console.log("sheet has completed processing")
console.log("Finished Processing sheets")
console.log("Processing Errors")
```

Here is the code.

```
module.exports = async function(file) {
var sheets = await readXLSX(file, { getSheets: true })

  await Promise.each(Object.values(sheets), (sheet)=>{
    readXLSX(file, { sheet }).then((data)=>{
      //Process sheet data here
      return processSheet(data)
    })
  })
  console.log("Finished Processing sheets")
  console.log("Processing Errors")

}
var processSheet = async function(data){
//Do some processing and write excel data to database
await db.table('some_table')
.insert(.....)

return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
console.log("sheet has completed processing")
resolve()
})
}
```

Comment: `await Promise.each` expects the second parameter to be a function that returns a promise. You are not doing that. If you `return readXLSX(...)` I think your problem will be (partially?) solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed `readXLSX` returns a `Promise` because you use `.then()` on it. `then` returns a `Promise` so if you want `Promise.each` to work as expected, you should do `return readXLSX(...).then(...);`

Here is an example with your code simplified:

```js
//Promise.each emulation
Promise.each = function(arr, fn) {
  if(!Array.isArray(arr)) return Promise.reject(new Error("Non array passed to each"));
  if(arr.length === 0) return Promise.resolve(); 
  return arr.reduce(function(prev, cur) { 
    return prev.then(() => fn(cur))
  }, Promise.resolve());
};

//readXLSX emulation
var readXLSX = function(val){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(val);
        }, 1);
    });
};

var test = async function(file) {
  var sheets = { foo: 'bar', foo2: 'bar2' }

  await Promise.each(Object.values(sheets), (sheet)=>{
      return readXLSX(sheet).then((data)=>{
          //Process sheet data here
          return processSheet(data)
      });
  })
  console.log("Finished Processing sheets")
  console.log("Processing Errors")

};
var processSheet = async function(data){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    console.log("sheet has completed processing", data)
    resolve()
  })
};

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your `Promise.each` callback doesn't `return` the promise, so the loop cannot wait for it.

```
Promise.each(Object.values(sheets), (sheet)=>{
  return readXLSX(file, { sheet }).then(processSheet)
//^^^^^^
})
```

Or with `async`/`await`:

```
module.exports = async function(file) {
  const sheets = await readXLSX(file, { getSheets: true })

  await Promise.each(Object.values(sheets), async (sheet) => {
//                                          ^^^^^
    const data = await readXLSX(file, { sheet })
    return processSheet(data)
  })
  console.log("Finished Processing sheets")
  console.log("Processing Errors")
}

async function processSheet(data) {
  await db.table('some_table').insert(…)
  console.log("sheet has completed processing");
  return undefined; // no need to construct a promise here
}
```